# StreamReader code raises exception after converting it to DesktopBridge APP

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-bridge

I have this small WPF application that uses below code. basically it Reads the said file to display content.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"Terms\License.txt", Encoding.UTF8))           {
....
}
```

This code works correctly in WPF Application.  But When ...
I use DesktopBridge to convert WPF into Appx and then Installed .Appx. 
The same code throws exception.

> Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException.

Any Clue ?  Any Assistance ?

Regards

Comment: Well, your code depends on Environment.CurrentDirectory. Use an absolute path.

Comment: you using a relative path. You can put a breakpoint in the`using`line and check the working directory path. Then you can ensure if this folder holds the `@"Terms\License.txt"` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I will not be able to debug once its converted to .appx.   Secondly It works perfecting fine during debug and runtime as long as its a WPF ExE.   I get this errors after WPF EXE is converted to .APPX using External Utility DesktopBridge.

The every reason for using relative path is , not to worry about absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the preparation guide for Desktop Bridge apps on MSDN and make the appropriate compatible code change to your app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

> Your app uses the Current Working Directory. At runtime, your
>   converted app won't get the same Working Directory that you previously
>   specified in your desktop .LNK shortcut. You need to change your CWD
>   at runtime if having the correct directory is important for your app
>   to function correctly.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform